# How can I count and keep track of values in a huge json file

Tags: python, json, data-structures

I have a huge json file , it has a key call type(the type of crime commited), date and time(date crime was commited) , and location(address or lat&long) among other keys with values. Im mostly interested in counting the days with the most crimes , counting what call types show up the most, and what location shows up the most also, the location can measure by the home address or pairing the latitude and longitude together. Python would probably be best  . THERES OVER 350 TYPES OF CALL TYPES ON A JSON WITH OVER 350K DATA ROWS. So everything time you see a new call type it should like create a new variable for that and keep track of it

i tried iterating threw it like a list but having issues . how can i attach to my code when its 62 mb , should i link to a file?

this is an example of data

```
[{"A": "incident_num", "B": "date_time", "C": "day", "D": "stno", "E": "stdir1", "F": "StreetName", "G": "streettype", "H": "FullAddress", "I": "call_type", "J": "disposition", "K": "beat", "L": "priority", "M": "lat", "N": "long"},
{"A": "P17060024503", "B": "6/14/2017 21:54", "C": "4", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "14TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 14TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "1151", "J": "O", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7054489", "N": "-117.1518696"},
{"A": "P17030051227", "B": "3/29/2017 22:24", "C": "4", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "14TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 14TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "1016", "J": "A", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7054489", "N": "-117.1518696"},
{"A": "P17060004814", "B": "6/3/2017 18:04", "C": "7", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "14TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 14TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "1016", "J": "A", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7054489", "N": "-117.1518696"},
{"A": "P17030029336", "B": "3/17/2017 10:57", "C": "6", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "14TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 14TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "1151", "J": "OT", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7054489", "N": "-117.1518696"},
{"A": "P17030005412", "B": "3/3/2017 23:45", "C": "6", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "911P", "J": "CAN", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
{"A": "P17020016091", "B": "2/10/2017 8:23", "C": "6", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "AU2", "J": "W", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
{"A": "P17040017368", "B": "4/11/2017 4:57", "C": "3", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "5150", "J": "CAN", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
{"A": "P17030048050", "B": "3/28/2017 6:30", "C": "3", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "1146", "J": "K", "K": "521", "L": "", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
{"A": "P17060037341", "B": "6/22/2017 10:19", "C": "5", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "242", "J": "K", "K": "521", "L": "1", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
{"A": "P17060008467", "B": "6/5/2017 19:27", "C": "2", "D": "10", "E": "", "F": "15TH", "G": "ST", "H": "10 15TH ST, San Diego, CA", "I": "5150", "J": "K", "K": "521", "L": "2", "M": "32.7057215", "N": "-117.1503498"},
```

i just want stats for like each call type that was made and how much time it was made , or what location has most crimes , what date had the most crimes etc ..

Comment: If this is a daily task I think you should store your data in a database so operations like you're mentioning are more efficient (and easy) to carry on.

Comment: no its not a daily task just some analytics i want to do, im sure if im able to count one column i can count others. But the call type is the difficult one because the call type has 300 different call types , and theres over 360k data points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pandas`:

```
import pandas as pd

raw_df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df = raw_df.rename(columns=raw_df.iloc[0]).drop(0)
df
```

Output:

```
    incident_num        date_time day stno stdir1 StreetName      ...      call_type disposition beat priority         lat          long
1   P17060024503  6/14/2017 21:54   4   10              14TH      ...           1151           O  521        2  32.7054489  -117.1518696
2   P17030051227  3/29/2017 22:24   4   10              14TH      ...           1016           A  521        2  32.7054489  -117.1518696
3   P17060004814   6/3/2017 18:04   7   10              14TH      ...           1016           A  521        2  32.7054489  -117.1518696
4   P17030029336  3/17/2017 10:57   6   10              14TH      ...           1151          OT  521        2  32.7054489  -117.1518696
5   P17030005412   3/3/2017 23:45   6   10              15TH      ...           911P         CAN  521        2  32.7057215  -117.1503498
6   P17020016091   2/10/2017 8:23   6   10              15TH      ...            AU2           W  521        2  32.7057215  -117.1503498
7   P17040017368   4/11/2017 4:57   3   10              15TH      ...           5150         CAN  521        2  32.7057215  -117.1503498
8   P17030048050   3/28/2017 6:30   3   10              15TH      ...           1146           K  521           32.7057215  -117.1503498
9   P17060037341  6/22/2017 10:19   5   10              15TH      ...            242           K  521        1  32.7057215  -117.1503498
10  P17060008467   6/5/2017 19:27   2   10              15TH      ...           5150           K  521        2  32.7057215  -117.1503498
```

Example of queries you can run:

```
>>> df['call_type'].value_counts()
5150    2
1016    2
1151    2
242     1
911P    1
AU2     1
1146    1
```

Comment: even its in json ? or has to be in csv ?

Comment: great its working , but can df['call_type'].value_counts() accept multiple columns in the list like df['call_type','date_time','FullAddress','priority'].value_counts()

Comment: @DavidArriaga Not natively, because the row indices wouldn't make sense. You would use a `for` loop for that.

Comment: for loop iterate over a list of columns and inside the loop we should the df[x].value_counts()

Comment: @DavidArriaga Yes. Also, you should *probably* ask a different question/read through the `pandas` documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Iterate the json file and store the required fields in assosiatve array. You can perform operation on it.

If the data has fixed column and structure you can store it in database like MySql and you can perform your required operations easily with simple queries.